# Is it possible to request elastic 2.3.5 using elastic client 6.8?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that ES documentation talks about client and server compatibility (2.x <-> 2.x or 5.x <-> 5.x). Nevertheless, I want to try to configure ES client 6.8 with 2.3.5 ES but I'm getting en error:

```
08:58:27.855 [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_worker][T#13]] WARN  o.e.transport.TcpTransport - exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx, remoteAddress=xxxxxx/xx.xx.xx.xx:9300}], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 180 hex: b4
```

I don't know if I have a configuration error or if it's an error that means it's definitely not possible to connect. I want to be sure that it is impossible.
My usages are simple fetches and updates.

My configuration:

```
public Client elasticClient(ElasticConfig config) {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "cluster-name")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
            .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "2s")
            .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "3s")
            .put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "1s")
            .build();

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

        config.getNodes().forEach(
            hostname -> {
                TransportAddress address = null;
                try {
                    address = new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), config.getPort());
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                client.addTransportAddress(address);
            }
        );

        return client;
    }
```

Comment: Way too many versions between 2.3.5 and 6.8, I would definitely not venture into investigating what's causing the issue. Just use an older client or upgrade your cluster